# Changing domain through 301 redirects - will I lose ranking position?

Tags: redirects, search-engine-indexing, ranking

I have a few articles that are in the top 3 of Google search results. They are currently accessed by the URL `http://example.com/myarticle1`.

Now, I want to move that article to the other URL `http://example.org/different-name-myarticle1`. The old URL is referenced in many places on the internet. I don't want to break the links so I setup a 301 redirect returned from the server with the new location. A browser works perfectly but I'm wondering if the indexing bot will follow the redirects and keep the ranking of my page? Are there any risks?

Comment: No worries mate! You did exactly the right thing. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you indeed seem to have done things perfectly with the 301 redirect, you might (temporarily) lose your rankings.

- This is due to the fact that Google is hesitant to immediately transfer all link metrics to new URLs after they redirect.
- Also, if the article indeed has a different name (as your example shows) then this might also impact your rankings.
- Furthermore, with each redirect you could lose some link juice, as referenced, for instance, in http://www.seoblog.com/2014/06/link-juice-lost-301-redirect/.

Comment: In order to mitigate as much risk as possible you could make sure to monitor your website closely in terms of all-things-SEO (title, meta, pagination, http headers, loading speed, https, redirects, mobile, canonical, etc. etc.) to ensure that you haven't missed anything in the setup of your new domain as compared to the old one.